# Moving our banking app current infrastructure to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Im working in a startup company and just recently been promoted into a solutions designer level. Although I have knowledge in AWS (passed developer and architect associate exam), I still don't have much experience in actual project work in AWS. Here is my dilemma:

We have a banking app made from a hybrid solution(angular/ionic). It makes back end calls to web services to do most of its functions. Web services are java based REST services deployed in Apache Tomcat. They are all stateless. In between the app and the web services, we make use of IBM'S mobile first platform (adapters). They handle things like security and session because our web services are stateless. Now we have to start to convert all of these into AWS.

I'm thinking using API Gateway with Lambda for the back end services. We could also use Federated Identities for SSO once authenticated via LDAP. My problem is on the IBM MFP adapters end. What AWS service would be a suitable replacement for this?

Comment: Did you think about Cognito, AWS Amplify or creating your own "Proxy Layer/Mobile First Layer" using AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 0):

- AWS Amplify should do it with some rewrite of code provided you are happy to dump the IBM MFP licence you have(just thinking from the cost perspective).

  Or
- Just deploy the IBM MFP on some linux ec2 instance.